# cuda version not installed on pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I have a cuda-capable gpu in my computer, and the version is NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660 Ti. The operating system is Windows10. According to the official website

https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

I opened anaconda prompt(anaconda 3) and entered the following line for installing pytorch

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

but when I enter this code in pycharm:

```
import torch
print(torch.cuda.is_available())
```

It returns False and this error appears:

```
UserWarning: CUDA initialization: CUDA driver initialization failed, you might not have a CUDA gpu. (Triggered internally at  ..\c10\cuda\CUDAFunctions.cpp:115.)
  return torch._C._cuda_getDeviceCount() > 0
```

Why is it like this? Doesn't this command

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.1 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```

by default try to install cuda version if i have a cuda-capable gpu?

This is the output of nvidia-smi

[image]

Comment: What cuda version do you have installed? Run `nvcc --version` in a cmd prompt to get your currently installed version

Comment: It says nvcc is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Maybe you might not have the right nvidia-driver installed to work with the specified cuda version. What is your output when you run `nvidia-smi` in a cmd prompt? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272028/how-does-anaconda-pick-cudatoolkit) for more information on how anacondas cudatoolkit package and drivers are connected.

Comment: I've edited the post and added the ouput of nvidia-smi.

Comment: Do I need to install CUDA Toolkit 11.4 from here?
https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local
because the command I used in anaconda prompt for installing pytorch had cudatoolkit=11.1

Comment: From the output you can see, that your current driver only supports up to cuda version 10.0 . You can either install the right cudatoolkit version in your anaconda environment `conda install cudatoolkit=10.0` or upgrade the driver for newer version. You can get the newest driver for your graphics card [here](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) .  I dont think installing the CUDA Toolkit is necessary, the conda package will take care of that.

Comment: Will the command conda install cudatoolkit=10.0 rewrite the previous version by itself? or should I enter other commands so that the base environment forgets the 11.1 version and considers the 10.0 version?

Comment: I am not sure how anaconda handles reinstalling packages with a different version, so maybe the safest way to go is to uninstall the current cudatoolkit by running `conda remove cudatoolkit` in your environment and then reinstalling with the new version

Comment: Thanks. I also have some environment activation problems that I have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68873770/pytorch-not-appearing-in-the-kernel-of-jupyter-notebook

Comment: The `conda install cudatoolkit=10.0` will replace any existing versions in the env - you do not need to do any remove steps.